# Isolate value that is not contained in one array from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to find the values in `arrayOne` that are not contained in each of the two groups in `arrayTwo`. In the scenario below I would like isolate `b` and `d` for `group1` and `a` and `b` for group2.

```
   arrayOne = ['a','b','c','d']
    
    arrayTwo = [{
        group1:[['a', 4],['c',8]],
        group2:[['c', 7],['d',11]]
    }]
```

I've tried several ways up at this point but can't seem to get the order correct. Here is what I currently have:

```
arrayTwo[0].group1.forEach(e => {
        console.log(e)
        arrayOne.forEach(f => {
            if(e[0] != f) {
                console.log(e[0])
            }
        })
    })
```

Expected result

```
b
d
```

Comment: You should put your expected result too, that will help other supporters in answering

Comment: Consider using [sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and calculate their difference. Also, 'isolate' is not the right description for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use "difference" calculation from [How to get the difference between two arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Example:

```js
const arrayOne = ['a','b','c','d']
    
const arrayTwo = [{
    group1:[['a', 4],['c',8]],
    group2:[['c', 7],['d',11]]
}]

const resultForGroup1 = arrayOne.filter(letter => !arrayTwo[0].group1.map(keyValue => keyValue[0]).includes(letter))

document.write(resultForGroup1)
```

Comment: The link and answer helped out tremendously. Thanks!